# Hide text using CSS to not take page space

Tags: html, css, hover

Currently I am having an issue when dealing with CSS and using Hover over a logo.

I have this logo that when hovered on, a body of text will appear underneath, then of course when moved away, this text disappears and the logo returns to normal.

The issue is that when this text is hidden, it is still taking up page space, so for instance when viewed on a mobile device, there is large blank spots where the text would appear when hovered on.

Is there anyway to say move this text to another point of the screen, or change the wrapping, so that it does not take this space. It is glaringly obvious these blank spots when scrolling on a mobile phone.

I have attached an example and changed the image and words to Fried Chicken, because who doesn't enjoy some finger licking good stuff.

```css
.logo2 {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.logo2 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: inline;
  display: block;
}

.logo__image2 {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform .5s;
  height: auto;
}

.logo__text2 {
  color: #636059;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: justify;
  text-transform: normal;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  position: inline;
  position: translateY(70px);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.logo2 .img-responsive {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo2:hover .logo__image2 {
  transform: translateY(-25px);
}

.logo2:hover .logo__text2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(550px);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<div class="logo2">
  <nav>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </nav>
  <img class="logo__image2" src="http://blueribbonfriedchicken.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/honeyDrippin.png" />
  <span class="logo__text2">
    <p> In a large resealable plastic bag, combine 2-2/3 cups flour, garlic salt, paprika, 2-1/2 teaspoons pepper and poultry seasoning. In a shallow bowl, beat eggs and water; add salt and the remaining flour and pepper. Dip chicken in egg mixture, then place in the bag, a few pieces at a time. Seal bag and shake to coat.</p>
    <p>In a deep-fat fryer, heat oil to 375°. Fry chicken, several pieces at a time, for 5-6 minutes on each side or until golden brown and juices run clear. Drain on paper towels. Yield: 8 servings. </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things can make text take up zero space:

1. Make the text element display: none (this makes the element completely disappear; can't be animated with CSS).
2. Make the text element `line-height: 0` or `height: 0` depending on your use case (can be animated with CSS). The element can disappear if you use `opacity: 0` as well.
3. Make the text element `position: absolute` which takes it out of the normal flow structure. You can anchor it to an absolute, relative, or fixed parent (can be animated more dynamically, but can get complicated).

Those are the most-used ones off the top of my head. Others are welcome to edit this answer and add to this list.

---

The solution to the asker's question in JSFiddle form:  [jsfiddle.net/v9swdxhj/2](http://jsfiddle.net/v9swdxhj/2)

*Note: I removed some unused elements, including an unclosed  element. Look out for those!*

Comment: Hey @Dom, cheers for the rapid response.

I went through these options although did not have the greatest success.
Here is what happened for all 3:

1) No luck, need to animate this text "appearing"/"disappearing" through CSS hover

2) I applied 'line-height: 0' for .logo_text2 and 'line-height: 1' for .logo2:hover .logo__text2, which initially does clear up this space. However very initially when hovering over and just for a moment when moving the mouse off can you see the words all cramped together from this change.

3) Similar to 2, as moving mouse off shows the original position

Comment: Let's focus on option #2, then. What if you try height instead of line-height? Height animates a little better. For animation, the element will need a default height provided (1rem is probably a good starting place). You can then apply overflow: hidden to the text to make it disappear (or use opacity instead).

Comment: There's a bit more going on here than I initially realized. I'd suggest you also convert `span.logo__text2` into a `<div>`. First, because having a `<p>` inside of a `<span>` isn't semantically correct and also because you really need a `display: block` (or at least `inline-block`) element to really manipulate the element's space.

Comment: No worries, I had a hunch this may of been causing some issues. Ill go test now and let you know

Comment: Apologies for the rookiness of this response but I have gone ahead and created a new div class called `<div class="DomText">` but I am having issues classifying the text inside this block to refer to in the CSS. I used a Span Class (e.g. `<span class="DomText__text2">`) but im not sure this is the correct method, especially since making the changes to the CSS for this class, the text just disappears.

Comment: I thought it might be easier to make you a JSFiddle. Is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/v9swdxhj/1/ Note: I removed some unused elements, including an unclosed `<a>` element. Look out for those!

Comment: Legend Dom, this worked perfect. Thanks so much mate for helping out on this! Cannot appreciate it enough!

Comment: Awesome. I'm happy to help. I moved the JSfiddle to the original answer for the benefit of anyone finding this in the future.